# ArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, covariance

I'm studying about covariance and contravariance in C#.

I understand it quite a bit already but I'm looking for some more technical details. I understand that because of array covariance I can implicitly cast `string [] array = new string[1]` to `object [] moreGeneralArray = array`.

Storing an `int` in this array will then throw `ArrayTypeMismatchException`.

I'm looking on a bit more technical details as to how this is checked? It appears that there is still somewhat of a type hidden behind the `object []` type that tells the runtime it's actually a string array?

Comment: Another interesting way to demonstrate unsafe array covariance is to try to pass `ref moreGeneralArray[0]` to a method expecting a `ref object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implicitly cast an object of type `string[]` to `object[]`, the backing store is still of type `string[]`.

According to Eric Lippert, this particular kind of covariance is broken. He sais that '*It was added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted to be able to support Java-like languages.*'

[Read more on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).